# Rewriting URL encoded hash character with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a single page website that uses the hash (#) to access different pages.
The problem is that some PDF viewers break my links encoding the hash character, replacing `#` with `%23`, so for example the link `my.app.com/#product/22` becomes `my.app.com/%23product/22`.
I'm trying to  correct this using an htaccess rule that rewrites the URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)%23(.*)$ /$1#$2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

but it doesn't seem to work, what can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the %-decoded URL-path. So, if the requested URL contains `%23` (a URL encoded `#`) then you need to match a literal `#` in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. Otherwise, your redirect seems to be OK.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)#(.*)$ /$1#$2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

The `NE` (`noescape`) flag is required here in order to prevent the `#` in the *substitution* being URL encoded in the redirect response.

Clear your browser cache before testing. And test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was exactly that the pattern needed to match the decoded `%23` character, so `^(.*)#(.*)$`!

Answer (score 0):

The # and everything after it should never get sent with the request.

That's just for linking to named a tags

Comment: That's true when the separator is a real `#` character, but when the character is encoded the entire URL including what is after the encoded `#` (`%23`) is sent to the server

Comment: Right, which is why you shouldn't need to worry about real # in your rules.